# How to get menu bar on both of my screens?

Tags: display, menu-bar

Is there anyway to get my menu bar to show up on both of my screens? I don't want to use display mirroring, I just want the menu to be mirrored on both screens.

I'm using 10.6, but if this is a reason to upgrade to 10.8 I will. I want this so bad:)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Mac OS X does not allow for this natively. However, there is a third-party tool called [SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) that purports to do just this. I have not used this myself, but you might want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little nervous to use this as the production appears to have been abandon in its early stages a few years ago:(

Comment: Apparently SecondBar doesn't exists anymore or has been renamed. Is there any replacement in 2019?

Comment: What about MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Secondbar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) for years and recommend it.  I'm currently using it with 10.8 but have used it with 10.7 and 10.6.  The only downside IMO is that it only mirrors the application menus and system time.  It will not show system icons such as WiFi, Bluetooth, Time Machine, etc.

You can also rearrange and resize windows quickly by right clicking on the red/yellow/green buttons (X - +) of any window.  This is useful when connecting a laptop to a display and the OS not remembering where you previously had windows.  I have some AppleScripts that automate this as well if you're interested.

Comment: I looked into using SecondBar a while ago, but I found a potential security issue that made me uninstall it pretty quickly. With the screen locked/blank (+password), moving the mouse would show the login box on my primary screen, and the menu bar on my second screen. This would allow someone to see what I'm working on while the computer was locked. This was under 10.6.x.

Comment: Apparently SecondBar doesn't exists anymore or has been renamed. Is there any replacement in 2019?